# Filter rows based on string arrangement

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that is a bit confusing but I have a column called branching logic which contains some patterns which are like a formula. The column called branching logic looks like this

```
dput(df)
df<-structure(list(column1 = c("John", "Jane", "Erick"),
                   column2 = c("J34", "J345", "Er456"),
Branching_Logic = c("Silva = '1' and Silva = '2' ", "Mary = '2' or Mary = '2' ", "Mango = '1' and Mango = '2'", "Mark = '1' and Mark= '2'")),

                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -3L))
```

Now I do want to loop through the rows of this column called Branching_Logic and filter out only rows having this pattern e.g of row1 has **[Silva = '1' and Silva = '2']**.

I have tried to solve the problem using dplyr but I get the error **column 1 has NA name**

```
df$Branching_Logic <- rownames(diff_df)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Branching_Logic, 'and'))
```

Expected results are a dataframe with filtered rows in Branching_Logic column which have that pattern, like this in this table

```
dput(df)
df<-structure(list(column1 = c("John", "Jane", "Erick"),
                   column2 = c("J34", "J345", "Er456"),
                   New_BranchingLogic = c("Silva = '1' and Silva = '2' ", "Mango = '1' and Mango = '2' ", "Mark = '1' and Mark= '2'")),

                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                     -3L))
```

Comment: Where do you have data for `John`, `Jane` and `Erick` ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah Its on the entire dataframe, let me edit the question to add them

Comment: @Ronak Shah edited

Comment: For me its completely unclear what you want. Perhaps try `filter(grepl("and", Branching_Logic))`

Comment: @Jimbou  Just trying to filter out rows in that column based on that organization

Comment: OK, then try my suggestoin.